# How to download file from dynamic url/ php function using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

Using Python 3 I am trying to download a report. I have tried

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://newss.statistics.gov.my/newss-portalx/ep/epDownloadContentSearch.seam?contentId=145851&actionMethod=ep%2FepDownloadContentSearch.xhtml%3AcontentAction.doDisplayContent'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'tmp_file.xlsx')
```

but to no avail; it has downloaded html instead. Is there a Python package that can handle a seemingly php function ( not sure ) url link like Internet Download Manager as below? Whereby it can detect the filename and performs download accordingly.

[image]

**Update 1**

If you put the url into web browser during the first time it will trigger login, but if you put in the url again (second time and onwards) it will trigger download.

Answer (score 1):

Python code runs fine however the page you are trying to download from requires login. You might have better luck using Selenium.

https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

**Update**

Since it works if you visit the page twice this works with Selenium

1. Install Selenium package using

   pip install selenium
2. Download Chrome webdriver which matches your version of Chrome from

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

3. Place the driver where you python script is located
4. Try this script

```
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://newss.statistics.gov.my/newss-portalx/ep/epDownloadContentSearch.seam?contentId=145851&actionMethod=ep%2FepDownloadContentSearch.xhtml%3AcontentAction.doDisplayContent')
browser.get('https://newss.statistics.gov.my/newss-portalx/ep/epDownloadContentSearch.seam?contentId=145851&actionMethod=ep%2FepDownloadContentSearch.xhtml%3AcontentAction.doDisplayContent')
time.sleep(2)

browser.quit()
```